# Phonegap build is unable to run on a lot of devices - why

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, phonegap-build

Somebody that are able to tell me why my app is unable to install on many devices from Google Play. I can not see why and there is no help from Google or I am unable to find out the reason in the Google systems.

For instance it is unable to install to Samsung Galaxy tablets

Here is my Config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.pcrypt.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Password Crypt</name>
    <description>Safe online storage of passwords</description>
    <author email="info@pcrypt.org" href="http://pcrypt.org">Password Crypt</author>
    <content src="index.html" />

    <allow-navigation href="https://pcrypt.org" />
    <allow-intent href="https://pcrypt.org" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <access origin="https://pcrypt.org" subdomains="true" />

    <!-- Plugins -->    
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-universal-clipboard" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" />

    <!-- Default settings -->
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />

    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" /> <!-- Will be hidden by code -->
    <preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="white" /> <!-- does not seam to work - or maybe only on windows? -->
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />  
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />  
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1500" />  

    <!-- Default icon -->
    <icon src="icon.png" /> 

    <!-- Default splash-->
    <splash src="splash.png" />  

    <platform name="android">    
      <!-- Settings -->
      <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
      <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
      <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
      <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" /> 
      <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
      <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
      <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />

      <!-- Icons -->
      <icon qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
      <icon qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
      <icon qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
      <icon qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />

      <!-- Splash -->
      <splash qualifier="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
      <splash qualifier="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
      <splash qualifier="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
      <splash qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />    
      <splash qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
      <splash qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
      <splash qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
      <splash qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    </platform>

    <platform name="ios">    
      <!-- Settings -->
      <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
      <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
      <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
      <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
      <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
      <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
      <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
      <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />

      <!-- Hide status bar -->
      <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
      <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
      <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" overwrite="true"> <false/> </gap:config-file>
      <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIStatusBarHidden" overwrite="true"> <true/> </gap:config-file>

      <!-- Icons -->
      <!--<icon height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
      <icon height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
      <icon height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
      <icon height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />

      <!- Splash
      <splash height="480" width="320" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" />
      <splash height="960" width="640" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" />
      <splash height="1136" width="640" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" />
      <splash height="1024" width="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" />
      <splash height="768" width="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" />

      <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
      <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
      <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
      <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
      <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
      -->

      <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
      <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>


      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon.png" width="180" height="180" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon60.png" width="60" height="60" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon120.png" width="120" height="120" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon76.png" width="76" height="76" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon152.png" width="152" height="152" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon40.png" width="40" height="40" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon80.png" width="80" height="80" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon57.png" width="57" height="57" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon114.png" width="114" height="114" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon72.png" width="72" height="72" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon144.png" width="144" height="144" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon29.png" width="29" height="29" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon58.png" width="58" height="58" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon50.png" width="50" height="50" />
      <icon src="res/icon/ios/pcrypt_icon100.png" width="100" height="100" />

    </platform>    

    <platform name="winphone">    
      <!-- Settings -->
      <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />

      <!-- Icons -->
      <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
      <icon role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />

      <!-- Splash -->
      <splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    </platform>      

</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything I can find that would cause the app not working besides the min SDK is 22 and that will make the app incomparable to 5.0 and lower. I tried your app on my own phone and it seemed to work fine for me. What exactly are people reporting the issue is?

Comment: No people have reported  anything because we have not started advertising etc. It is based on my own testing on some tablets and a look in the developer part of Google play where I can get a list of devices it can install on and a very long list of devices where it can not be installed - but I am unable to see why

Comment: I don't have access to that list but if you could provide a screenshot of the list or provide a short lost of what devices can and cannot work I might be able to tell you

Comment: I am for instance unable to install on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 N8010 with android 4.1.2

Comment: Any devices running Android 5.0 and lower won't work. Right now you have your minimum SDK of 22 which is android 5.1. Most devices do have android 5.1+ but if you do lower the SDK I wouldn't go any lower than 21.